# How to get better quality in fix resize image in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

I have 4608x3456 image that I want to adjust the size of. I want to adjust the resolution of the image to 640x480, yet when I do this the quality of the image drops. Is there a way to decrease image resolution and and still have a better image quality?

Resized Image 640x480 :

[image]

```
     Bitmap temobitmpa = loadScaledBitmapFromUri(path,640,480);

     return getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), temobitmpa);



     public Bitmap loadScaledBitmapFromUri(String filePath, int width, int height) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        // calc aspect ratio
        int[] retval = calculateAspectRatio(options.outWidth, options.outHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth,
                options.outHeight, width, height);

        Log.i("test", "sample size::" + options.inSampleSize);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, retval[0], retval[1],
                true);

    }


        private int[] calculateAspectRatio(int origWidth, int origHeight) {
            int newWidth = 640;
            int newHeight = 480;

            // If no new width or height were specified return the original bitmap
            if (newWidth <= 0 && newHeight <= 0) {
                newWidth = origWidth;
                newHeight = origHeight;
            }
            // Only the width was specified
            else if (newWidth > 0 && newHeight <= 0) {
                newHeight = (newWidth * origHeight) / origWidth;
            }
            // only the height was specified
            else if (newWidth <= 0 && newHeight > 0) {
                newWidth = (newHeight * origWidth) / origHeight;
            }
            // If the user specified both a positive width and height
            // (potentially different aspect ratio) then the width or height is
            // scaled so that the image fits while maintaining aspect ratio.
            // Alternatively, the specified width and height could have been
            // kept and Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT specified when scaling, but this
            // would result in whitespace in the new image.
            else {
                double newRatio = newWidth / (double) newHeight;
                double origRatio = origWidth / (double) origHeight;

                if (origRatio > newRatio) {
                    newHeight = (newWidth * origHeight) / origWidth;
                } else if (origRatio < newRatio) {
                    newWidth = (newHeight * origWidth) / origHeight;
                }
            }

            int[] retval = new int[2];
            retval[0] = newWidth;
            retval[1] = newHeight;
            return retval;
        }


        private int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth,
                int dstHeight) {
            final float srcAspect = (float) srcWidth / (float) srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float) dstWidth / (float) dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            } else {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Quality and image resolution are synonymous, so it is really just a play on words. Basically, decreasing the image resolution is the same thing as decreasing the quality because both are defined by how many pixels the image consist of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this image scaling library, it gives a very good image quality.

https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr

Comment: But android not provide BufferedImage  object